# Issue with "white-space: nowrap" on Chrome 78.0.3904.70

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, whitespace

Since the release of Chrome v78.0.3904.70, I am seeing issues with using `&nbsp;` with the CSS property `white-space: nowrap;`. The non-breaking space seems to cause a line break. When using `text-overflow: ellipsis`, the actual text will not display as it is broken outside of the container. Only seems to happen if the text is too long to display.

```css
.box-inline {
    max-width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 16px;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="mar-rgt box-inline text-sm"><span class="label" style="background: rgb(176, 223, 246);"></span>&nbsp;Not meeting expecations</div>
```

[image]

It's causing a few display problems on our applications. Is this a bug or is there something wrong with my code?

This code is being rendered in React 16.

Comment: Chrome 78.0.3904.87 is released, I can't reproduce the issue with it(tried your snippet). Can you try and let me know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the release of M79 on December the 10th 2019 as referenced here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1017465

Answer (score 1):

You can remove **"nbsp;"** and use margin or padding, it will work fine.

The bug is already reported https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1017465

Comment: Thanks for referencing the reported bug. I wish it was as simple as just remove the &nbsp; but this occurs in live systems that can not just be changed without going through strict release processes.